# MySQL - Need to find MAX of SUM query

Tags: mysql

I need to find user who has the most to pay for reservations, and if there are 2 or more users with same amount to show all of them, so I need MAX of SUM.

My table reservation shortened looks like this:

```
reservation_id, user_id, performance_id, amount_to_pay, date
```

So I ahve this code

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(amount_to_pay) FROM reservation GROUP BY user_id
```

And I got

```
User 1 - 9000
User 2 - 9000
User 3 - 5000
```

It needs to show User 1 and User 2 with 9000.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use the `HAVING` clause with a correlated subquery that gets the `max` value between all the `sums` and restrict the rows to those whose `SUM(amount_to_pay)` equals the `max_value`.

```
SELECT
   user_id,
   SUM(amount_to_pay) AS total
FROM
   reservation AS r
GROUP BY
   user_id
HAVING
   total = (SELECT SUM(amount_to_pay) AS tot
            FROM reservation
            GROUP BY user_id
            ORDER BY tot DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Online example: [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ixrj8kzzX28bk9m6b5dtAj/0)

---

## UPDATE POST COMMENTARY:

For `sum` only the `active` reservations you could take one of the next approaches:

**A)** Add the restriction on outer query and subquery:

```
SELECT
   user_id,
   SUM(amount_to_pay) AS total
FROM
   reservation AS r
WHERE
   status = "active"
GROUP BY
   user_id
HAVING
   total = (SELECT SUM(amount_to_pay) AS tot
            FROM reservation
            WHERE status = "active"
            GROUP BY user_id
            ORDER BY tot DESC LIMIT 1)
```

**B)** Use `CASE WHEN ... END` inside the `SUM()` method:

```
SELECT
   user_id,
   SUM(CASE WHEN status = "active" THEN amount_to_pay END) AS total
FROM
   reservation AS r
GROUP BY
   user_id
HAVING
   total = (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN status = "active" THEN amount_to_pay END) AS tot
            FROM reservation
            GROUP BY user_id
            ORDER BY tot DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Online example: [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ixrj8kzzX28bk9m6b5dtAj/1)

Comment: This is ok, but now I have one little problem. In my reservation I have status (active/inactive) and I need to SUM only active reservations. I've tried this but it doesn't work:

SELECT
   user_id,
   SUM(amount_to_pay) AS total
FROM
   reservation AS r
GROUP BY
   user_id
HAVING
   total = (SELECT SUM(amount_to_pay) AS tot
            FROM reservation
            WHERE status = "active"
            GROUP BY user_id
            ORDER BY tot DESC LIMIT 1)

and also status = "active" before GROUP BY user_id in first query.

Comment: Everything is fine, thank you so much for quick and accurate answer.

Comment: @1005 you are welcome, consider to upvote my answer when you gain enough reputation